# how to get the list of pattern match folders using ansible

Tags: find, ansible, pattern-matching

ansible find module is not listing the matching pattern. 
here is my directory structure

```
path: /home/ryan/ws

.
|___file1.txt
|___file2.yaml
|___file3.jar
|___service1
| |___1.0.7.0
|   |___service1_1.0.7.0.jar
| |___1.0.19.0
|   |___service1_1.0.19.0.jar
| |___1.0.123.0
|   |___service1_1.0.123.0.jar
|____service2
| |___1.0.23.0
|   |___service2_1.0.23.0.jar
| |___1.0.9.0
|   |___service2_1.0.9.0.jar
| |___1.0.143.0
|   |___service2_1.0.143.0.jar
|____service3
| |___1.0.2.0
|   |___service3_1.0.2.0.jar
| |___1.0.4.0
|   |___service3_1.0.4.0.jar
| |___1.0.13.0
|   |___service3_1.0.13.0.jar
```

like wise i have many folders nearly 20 for each service. SO i wanted to list all the directories inside each service.

here is what i am trying

```
- hosts: myserver
  become: true
  become_user: myuser
  vars:
    workspace_path: /home/ryan/ws

tasks:

- name: find folders from location
  find:
    paths: "{{ workspace_path }}/{{ item }}"
    file_type: directory
    patterns: "1.0.*.0/"
    recurse: yes
    use_regex: yes
  with_items:
    - service1                         
    - service2               
    - service3         
    - app1
    - app2 
  register: files_to_delete

- debug: var=files_to_delete
```

Can someone give me better way to list the folders alone in ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include a path separator in your pattern. It should read

```
patterns: "1.0.*.0"
```

The catch is to precede the '*' with a '.' as in foo.*bar 
Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/vpnwall-services/5e5cc8c11384d6e42e1760b73471c620